# Error when declaring parameter in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters

I am trying to create a stored procedure that utilizes a variable number of parameters. As I am pretty new to writing stored procedures and TSQL in general, I decided to try and write it with only one parameter. However, I keep getting an error stating "Must declare scalar variable @FirstName" when I try to execute it. Right now, I am trying to store the SQL statement in another variable, @sql. My procedure looks like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetEmployeeByParameters]
(@FirstName varchar(50))

AS

BEGIN

    DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(4000)
    SET @sql = 'SELECT e.* from Employee e
               WHERE e.FirstName = @FirstName'
    EXEC (@sql)
END
```

I've looked elsewhere and tried EXEC sp_execute @sql which didn't work. Strangely, what does work is when I don't declare the @sql variable and instead just write my query normally. Since that is the case, I'm assuming there is some error in my usage of the SET and EXEC functions. I'm also not 100% sure that I'm using BEGIN and END properly. The way I understood it is that BEGIN and END separate SQL statements into logical blocks, and thus are more commonly used when IF comes into play. Could anyone tell me what exactly is going on with my parameter here? It's really confusing me as to why SQL Server thinks it's not declared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable parameter needs to be outside the quotes.

```
SET @sql = N'SELECT e.* from Employee e
             WHERE e.FirstName = ''' + @FirstName + ''''
```

Or, better yet, run it without any dynamic SQL.

```
SELECT e.* 
    from Employee e
    WHERE e.FirstName = @FirstName
```

Comment: Thanks Joe, that worked like a charm! If I understand correctly then, the variable parameter does in fact need to be inside quotes,  but just not part of the @ sql string? That's the only reason I can think of for the triple and quadruple single quotes surrounding @ FirstName

Answer (score 1):

Because

```
'Select  ... @FirstName'
```

is not the same as

```
Select ... @FirstName
```

One is a string and the other is a SQL Query

What you should do instead is

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetEmployeeByParameters]
(@FirstName varchar(50))

AS

BEGIN

    DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(4000)
    SET @sql = 'SELECT e.* from Employee e
               WHERE e.FirstName = ''' + @FirstName + ''''
    EXEC (@sql)
END
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing up the difference between the actual query and a string; that helps!

Answer (score 1):

When you execute dynamic sql, you are switching contexts and variables don't move between contexts.   Once you declare the SQL statement as a string, everythign must be provided to that string in order for it to recognize it.

Obviously, you don't need dynamic SQL in this case, but once method of doing it is like so:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetEmployeeByParameters] 
  (@FirstName varchar(50))      
AS
      BEGIN
          DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(4000)
       SET @sql = 'SELECT e.* from Employee e
                  WHERE e.FirstName = @FirstName'
       EXEC sp_executeSQL @sql, N'@Firstname varchar(50)', @FirstName
   END
```

sp_executeSQL allows you to declare internal parameters (the second clause), and supply them with values (the last clause).

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your query to the following as the @Firstname variable is not in scope:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetEmployeeByParameters]
(@FirstName varchar(50))

AS

BEGIN

    DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(4000)
    SET @sql = 'SELECT e.* from Employee e
               WHERE e.FirstName = ''' + @FirstName + ''''
    EXEC (@sql)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this body, without "dynamic" query

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetEmployeeByParameters]
(@FirstName varchar(50))

AS

BEGIN

    SELECT e.* from Employee e
               WHERE e.FirstName = @FirstName
END
```

**OR**

using dynamic query do not include variables itselves into the script - do concatenate them with the script and **do not forget to properly quote them**.

Comment: @Chris J - Thanx for the note, corrected an answer a little bit

Answer (score 0):

As this is a "search" type query your doing with a variable number of params, you need to build the string up bit by bit -- you're on the right lines that it needs to be dynamic, but you also need to avoid SQL injection attacks (google "Little Bobby Tables"). Thus you need to use a parameterised dynamic SQL statement:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetEmployeeByParameters]
    @FirstName VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(4000)

    SET @sql = 'SELECT e.* FROM Employee e WHERE 1 = 1'
    IF @FirstName IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + ' AND FirstName = @pFirstName'
    END
    -- More IF statements, building up the query

    EXEC sp_ExecuteSQL @sql, N'@pFirstName VARCHAR(50)', @FirstName
```

The second and third params map the @FirstName parameter to the query's "internal" parameters (which I normally prefix with a 'p' or 'param' just to differentiate them from the stored procedure's own parameters).

You extend the sp_Exceute as appropriate each time you add a new parameter to search by, so you might end up doing:

```
    EXEC sp_ExecuteSQL @sql,' N'
              @pFirstName   VARCHAR(50),
              @pSurName     VARCHAR(50),
              @pDateOfBirth DATETIME', @FirstName, @Surname, @DateOfBirth
```

Comment: Chris, that's just what I was thinking. I was trying to do something similar before with the IF NOT NULL statements, but I kept running into this 'Must declare scalar variable' issue which is cleared up now. Thanks for the explanation on sp_ExecuteSQL! Would I use BEGIN ... END inside each IF statement in this case?

Comment: You don't have to -- I do it out of habit of definsive programming as it makes is clearer (when it comes to maintenance) where the IF starts and ends if another developer changes the indenting or something. One (of many) discussions on this theme can be found at http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?AlwaysUseBracesOnIfThen (talks about braces as per C, Java, C# etc but the same arguments apply here as well).